# How to Update Items with same ID in VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am Using VB.Net 2015 , and working with MS Access DataBase.
I have one Invoice that has many Items, for Example Invoice Number 2 has Orange , Apple and Banana , When view Invoice Number 2 in DataGrid and change Banana Item in DataGrid to Lemon using

```
"UPDATE Item_Invoice SET Item_Name=@Item_Name,Item_Type=@Item_Type,Item_Quantity=@Item_Quantity,Item_Purchase_Price=@Item_Purchase_Price,Item_Total_Cost=@Item_Total_Cost Where Invoice_No=" & CInt(txtInvoiceNo.Text) & "  " ,  all items become Lemon.
```

All Items Become Lemon , Because the Update statement Updates all items with Invoice_No 2 , any Idea how to overcome and fix the problem. Thanks in Advance

```
 For i = 0 To DGPurchase.Rows.Count - 2
                ObjCommand.Parameters.Clear()
                ObjCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Item_Invoice SET Item_Name=@Item_Name,Item_Type=@Item_Type,Item_Quantity=@Item_Quantity,Item_Purchase_Price=@Item_Purchase_Price,Item_Total_Cost=@Item_Total_Cost Where Invoice_No=" & CInt(txtInvoiceNo.Text) & "  "
                ObjCommand.Connection = myConnection

                ItmName = DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString
                ItmType = DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
                ItmQuantity = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
                itmTotalCost = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
                ItmPurPrice = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)

                ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Name", ItmName)
                ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Type", ItmType)
                ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Quantity", ItmQuantity)
                ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Total_Cost", itmTotalCost)
                ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Purchase_Price", ItmPurPrice)
                ' ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Invoice_No", InvNo)
                ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                'ObjCommand.Dispose()

            Next I
```

[DB Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrIO1.jpg)

Comment: Could you paste your table structure, please? It would be useful

Comment: Well.. i guess you should add the item name you want to change to your where clause

Comment: You are going about it the most difficult way possible.  If you are using a DGV, then also use a DataTable and DataAdapter.  Then it is just `myDA.Update(myDT)` to update anything that needs to be updated.  The DB Provider objects do all the work.  You should also take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You should create an unique id (P_Id PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT) for each row from your database and use that id for identifying the row. Otherwise I don't see and easy solution for identifying the row. Maybe you should old value in where clause besides the invoice id in order to find which row needs to be updated.

Comment: @Pikoh the item comes from the datagridview , and I am talking to many Items in the invoice 10, 20 .. moreover I want to update the row information not item name only.

Comment: can you make it clear by code, If I added a primary Key for example 1 Orange , 2 Apple , 3 Banana , and changed Banana to Lemon how can make change to Banana only using the primary Key and InvoiceNo = 2 . BY the way invoice number in uniqe but itme name can be same for many invoices. Thanks

Comment: In your gridview you should keep a hidden column with primary key and that make that row unique. You update query should use primary key in where clause to identify the row.

Comment: It seems it will work with assigning the Primary key to a variable and pass it to the Update statement where condition , so I can update each row separately in the loop. I will try this solution hope it works. Thanks. Note: every time I have to pass to all rows and update them to make sure if any row has any change. means pass the PK to update Statement for all rows to update all of them.

Comment: I got an Idea but I am not sure if it is a good choice. Is it ok to delete the invoice and recreating (Insert) it again with modification , it will be easier . I mean delete Invoice number 2 with all its contents and creating a new one with same number and new modified contents. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

It works fine now by deleting and recreating(insert) with the new information , Actually it is more useful to use insert instead of update in case user added new items to the DatagridView.
This is the finall code works perfect:

```
 ObjCommand.CommandText = " Delete from Item_Invoice where Invoice_No=" & CInt(txtInvoiceNo.Text) & " "

                ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                ObjCommand.Parameters.Clear()

                For i = 0 To DGPurchase.Rows.Count - 2
                    ObjCommand.Parameters.Clear()

                    ObjCommand.CommandText = "Insert into Item_Invoice (Invoice_No,Item_Name,Item_Type,Item_Quantity,Item_Total_Cost,Item_Purchase_Price) values (@Invoice_No,@Item_Name,@item_Type, @Item_Quantity,@Item_Total_Cost,@Item_Purchase_Price)"

                    ItmName = DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString
                    ItmType = DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
                    ItmQuantity = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
                    itmTotalCost = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
                    ItmPurPrice = CDbl(DGPurchase.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)

                    ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Invoice_No", InvNo)
                    ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Name", ItmName)
                    ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Type", ItmType)
                    ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Quantity", ItmQuantity)
                    ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Total_Cost", itmTotalCost)
                    ObjCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Item_Purchase_Price", ItmPurPrice)
                    ObjCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


                Next I
```

**Thank you for your helpful comments.**